# How to confirm if FileVault encryption has fully completed

Tags: macos, filevault

How to confirm FileVault encryption has fully completed? While it's in progress, `diskutil apfs list | grep 'Encryption Progress' ; fdesetup status` will shows percentage of conversion.

Later is there any way to know 100% encryption is completed?

Comment: I was about to flag this question as a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/60683/45492 but noticed that `diskutil apfs list` does not mention encryption status (anymore?). Is that a recent change? `diskutil cs list` works as expected for non-APFS volumes.

Comment: Excellent connections to the main thread and [this one for troubleshooting](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/160161/) @n1000

Answer (score 3):

**APFS volumes**

It seems that the only way to tell for APFS volumes is to use `fdesetup status`. [This fantastic blog](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2017/11/13/apfs-encryption-status-check-script/) offers a [script](https://github.com/rtrouton/rtrouton_scripts/tree/master/rtrouton_scripts/check_apfs_encryption) which basically uses that command to determine the status. In the article it reads:

> If encrypted, the following message is displayed:
>
> `FileVault is On.`
>
> If not encrypted, the following message is displayed:
>
> `FileVault is Off.`

These are basically the outputs of `fdesetup status`.

**Non-APFS volumes**

For non-APFS volumes there is more information. Try `diskutil cs list` or `diskutil cs list | grep "Conversion Status"`, respectively and look for `Conversion Status`. See also the [accepted answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/60729/45492).

```
$ diskutil cs list

CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX
    =========================================================
    Name:         VolumeXY
    Status:       Online
    Size:         196521975808 B (196.5 GB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk2s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     196521975808 B (196.5 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
        Encryption Status:       Locked
        Conversion Status:       Complete
        High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
        |                        Passphrase Required
        |                        Accepts New Users
        |                        Has Visible Users
        |                        Has Volume Key
        |
        +-> Logical Volume XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  -none-
            Status:                Locked
            Size (Total):          196169654272 B (196.2 GB)
            Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
            LV Name:               SD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```