# How to check encryption status (completeness) of an external disk?

Tags: macos, filevault

When I click on an external USB disk in Finder's Sidebar it shows it is still encrypting (which is expected):

[image: disk encrypting]

`diskutil` shows only `Encrypted: Yes` in CLI and GUI.

Is there any way to check the current status of encryption (percentage complete)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type the following command in Terminal you will get all sorts of info on all the corestorage volumes currently attached to your Mac, including the conversion status you are looking for:

```
diskutil cs list
```

There are more answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60683/how-to-view-progress-when-encrypting-a-disk).

One of my favorites is Nick Bedford's answer towards the bottom of that page that gives you just the status of each volume without all the other info.

```
diskutil cs list | grep -e "Conversion" -e "Volume Name"
```